# rsync filtering for .R extension not working

Tags: bash, rsync

Here's what I'm using:

```
rsync -rav --include '*/' --exclude '*' --include '*.R' user@remote:/folder/. .
```

I'm trying to copy all .R files in the remote folder and all its subdirectories. The result is that all the directories are copied, but empty.

Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm referencing this post: [rsync copy over only certain types of files using include option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111562/rsync-copy-over-only-certain-types-of-files-using-include-option).

Comment: put `-exclude '*'` after `-include '*.R'` should be enough I think

Comment: See also your linked question at SO saying "*For rsync version 3.0.6 or higher, the order needs to be modified*"

Comment: Not quite a duplicate because the issue here is the omission of `--prune-empty-dirs` and that isn't even mentioned in the proposed duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You need two alterations and should consider one recommendation

- Include and exclude directives are processed left to right, so you need to include the `.R` files before you exclude everything (else)
- Use `--prune-empty-dirs` so that only relevant directories are created on the destination
- You don't need `-r` as it's implied by `-a`

So

```
rsync -av --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*.R' --exclude '*' user@remote:/folder/ .
```